# CountDownTimer inestable segun verision de Android / Ahorro Bateria

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

Actualmente necesito que mi aplicación pasado los 5 minutos realize una accion en mi caso cerrar la session, en mis emuladores y mi telefono fisico anda de 10 pero en algunos telefonos no funciona, no estoy seguro si el ahorro de bateria podria hacer que no cuente el tiempo con CountDownTimer o que podria hacer que el tiempo no disminuya, necesito que el tiempo cuente por mas que la pantalla se bloquee o este en segundo plano actualmente uso

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    Context context = null;
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval,Context context) {
        super(startTime, interval);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Login.class);

        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.SessionExpirada),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Luego tengo otro metodo que reinicia cuando la persona iteractua

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){
    super.onUserInteraction();
   if(!Globals.getContadorSalidaON()){
       countDownTimer.cancel();
       countDownTimer.start();
   }
}
```

Por lo que esto me anda bien en algunos y en otros simplemente no anda, podria utilizar otro componente que cumpla con mis requerimientos o podria fixear al CountDownTimer para que siempre ande incluso en segundo plano y en ahorro de bateria

Comment: Hola Bruno, ¿Usas un servicio para llamar el contador?

Comment: Jorge lo llamo en memoria simplemente

Comment: @Jorgesys tu me sugieres usar un servicio? me indicarias maso menos como buscarlo un poquito mas de info mas tecnica

Comment: La sesión es remota (api rest) o local al dispositivo? En todo caso por que pensas que necesitas un timer para cerrar la sesión en lugar de simplemente medir el tiempo transcurrido entre interacciones?

Comment: @Juan es localmente, y uso un timer porque jsutamente quiero medir tiempos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Juan es localmente, y uso un timer porque jsutamente quiero medir
>   tiempos

Esta respuesta no contesta como implementar un timer que dispare un cierre de sesión, sino como "cerrar" una sesión local midiendo el tiempo transcurrido y comparando contra un límite predefinido.

La solución consiste en guardar un valor `long` con la hora devuelta por `System.currentTimeMillis()` cada vez que se interactua con la app, y comparar este valor contra el anterior para determinar si pasó mas del tiempo límite.

La comparación se logra haciendo la diferencia `horaInteraccionActual - horaUltimaInteracción`. El resultado de la diferencia son milisegundos así que para llevarlo a minutos hay que dividir por 60000.

Para conservar el valor de la última interacción podemos persistirlo en `SharedPreferences`.
Esta variable puede ser leida en `onResume()` y guardada en `onPause()`.

La solución es simple comparado con las aternativas que involucran el uso de un servicio con CountdownTimer, o usando AlarmManager. Y desde el punto de vista práctico lo que se obtiene como resultado es muy similar: *Transcurrido un determinado tiempo el usuario no puede usar la app sin autenticarse*.

La diferencia es que no puede notificarse el cierre de sesión al cumplirse el tiempo (5 minutos en la pregunta), y si hay que hacer algún trabajo de cierre, éste se demora hasta la próxima interacción del usuario. (Aunque esto es discutible dado que una solución con AlarmManager puede estar sujeta a demoras también).

**El activity:**

```
public class TimedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String APP_PREFS = "AppPrefs";
    private static final String PRF_UMA_INTERACCION = "ultima_interaccion";
    private static final int TIEMPO_LIMITE_MINS = 5;
    private long ultimaInteraccion = -1;
    private SharedPreferences prefs = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ultimaInteraccion = prefs.getLong(PRF_UMA_INTERACCION, -1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putLong(PRF_UMA_INTERACCION, ultimaInteraccion);
        editor.commit();
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Un ejemplo de interaccion **/
    public void unaInteraccion(){
        if(isSesionValida()){

            //Ejecutar interaccion

            interaccionConcretada();
        }else{
            cerrarSesion();
            pedirLogin();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Valida que se esté en la ventana de tiempo permitida para la sesión
     * @return true si se está en la ventana, y false si se está en la ventana o si no
     * hay una última interacción contra que comparar
     */
    private boolean isSesionValida(){
        boolean rtn;
        if(ultimaInteraccion == -1){
            rtn = false;
        }else {
            long horaActual = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int tiempoTranscurridoMins = (int) ((horaActual - ultimaInteraccion) / 60000);
            rtn = tiempoTranscurridoMins <= TIEMPO_LIMITE_MINS;
        }
        return rtn;
    }

    /**
     * Método de conveniencia para llamar cuando se quiere acutalizar la hora de la
     * última interacción. Presumiblemente, después de procesar la interacción actual.
     */
    private void interaccionConcretada(){
        ultimaInteraccion = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private void cerrarSesion(){
        // Si el cierre de sesión requiere hacer algo más se puede hacer acá
    }


    private void pedirLogin(){
        boolean autenticado = false;

        // Pedir autenticación para abrir nuevamente una sesion.

        autenticado = <resultado de la autenticación>; // true si se autentica al usuario y false si no se autentica
        if(autenticado){
            interaccionConcretada();
            ...; //Ir a pantalla principal por ejemplo
        }
    }
}
```